# Duplicate Desktop Icons

Tags: 15.10, desktop-icons

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 from Ubuntu 15.04. The process went smoothly. However after the restart I found that all my 15.04 desktop icons were duplicated. A ls -l of the Desktop location for my logon showed only one listing of desktop icons. If I delete any icon both of them disappear but the Deleted items only display the one item deleted.

How do I stop this behaviour? See this link to a brief video of the issue.

https://youtu.be/O1U28vXv7gc

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK there has been little feedback. Here is what worked for me. I simply installed the "Gnome Desktop" as another work environment on my system. So now when I login with the Gnome desktop there is never a double icon problem. I have since installed other desktops with a good result. I am therefore considering removing and reinstalling Ubuntu's default desktop but have not done so as yet. Given the fact installing another desktops solved the problem for me it is likely reinstalling the Ubuntu desktop will bring about a good result as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the exact same problem. Out of 3 computers we upgraded, only one is showing the symptoms.

I found someone with the same problem in 15.04, see solution there:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2286043

I will update my system first, then try it.

Comment: I have now tried it. It did fix the double icon problem, however, it destroyed my ability to set a desktop background, and any app I use is "sticking" as a desktop background when minimised or closed...

Comment: OK, I attempted that operation as well gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false and it did the same. Basically it nuked my desktop back ground. In my effort to look a little further while in this state I logged on as a different user and for a moment the profile also had a wallpaperless screen. I check for the double icon issue and it persisted. I logged back on as myself and didi the following to reverse the desktop wallpaper result and windows not closing down.  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true ....

Comment: My system operates normally again but the original issue of double icons remains... I need some pointers here. That solution: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2286043  appears to apply to Cinnamon ....

Comment: Also the pkill nautilus gives the same outcome and screws the windows where they stop functioning and will not close down etc. It made the windows sought of ""vibrate"" as well! So do not do the pkill thing...

Comment: Today I tried this .... I logged off and on three times without opening any applications. I know it sounds futile but on the third time I logged on the duplicate icons disappeared of their own accord? However if I restart the PC the issue is back until I log off and on again multiple times. This is just an observation I thought I may share should it be of any help those those who know.

Comment: OK I stand corrected. When the PC is turned on or restarted the double icon issue results once logged on. Should I log off and then on again (without the PC restarting) the issue goes away.

Comment: Can anyone give guidance on this - The issue still occurs. I need to log off and then on again each time the PC is turned on to temporary fix the Ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. In my case the problem was that nautilus and nemo were installed on my system and with removing one of them fixed the duplicated items. I hope this helps.